# getting error at fixed android codes

Tags: android, eclipse

I just want to start code at android. I install all the necessary things but when i open a project ı see these codes first:

```
package com.example.firstapp;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;

public class FirstApp extends Activity {

 @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_first_app);
 }

 @Override
 public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_first_app, menu);
    return true;
 }
 }
```

I got errors here;

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_first_app);
```

and here;

```
getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_first_app, menu);
```

I recommends to add import "R". when i add it the probşem goes on.

Can anybody help me?

edit: also res->layout file says "The project target (Android 4.1) was not properly loaded."

Comment: Try to clean and then re-build your application.

Comment: @feritenişer Clean your Project and check

Comment: You just mentioned that when you import "R", the problems goes on. What else do you want?

Comment: ı tried it never works.. check the question again i edited it

Comment: @Andy Res i imported "R". Then it found problem about "activity_first_app".. with no recommend

Comment: see if my answer can help you.

Comment: seems like `R.java` is not being generated. Close eclipse, find your project folder, delete `bin\\` and `gen\\` folders, open eclipse and give clean the project. if this doesn't help your environment is probably not setup properly. it could be an issue with eclipse,adt,sdk,java ...

Answer (score 0):

Also, make sure you import your application resource class, not the built in Android's class.

With other words, you should have this import statement:

```
import com.example.R;
```

instead of:

```
import android.R;
```

Answer (score 0):

your Application is missing resources.

Build and clear your application 
 and if there is  any  android.R import please delete this and bulid as well as clear your procject. this may solve your problem